# The operation was rejected by your operating system

Tags: reactjs

I was in a coding bootcamp last year and have not used vsc in a good while since, but am trying to get back into coding and am making a react app. I tried making a new react-app as i would in the past, but it could not make a template due to being outdated? i tried 'npm uninstall -g create-react-app' as suggested by most then just trying to create it again. problem being when i do i get lines of ERR one of which says,

"The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user"

i have tried anything, anything safe, i can find but nothing will give me access. what exactly is this? i am logged in as i just did and even said lat log in at so and so time meaning my user account is logged in. anything helps, but i guess i missunderstand what is happening here as i am not totally well versed in much of this yet. thank you for your time and helping a newbie out!

Comment: This likely means that the command line operation you are running is trying to delete a file that requires elevated privledges. If you use linux or macos try using the `sudo` command, or if you use windows, try running the terminal as admin.

Comment: @dwjohnston Thank you that did work. I'm still learning and relearning commands and why it would do these things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)